# How to fix error cannot read property of undefined using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i get error cannot read property of undefined using react and typescript?

what i am trying to do?

i have a parentComponent within which i make a query to get some data "itemData". and pass this itemData to the ChildComponent.

in the childComponent i am getting one property from itemData that is availableItems and passing it to Select menu options.

below is the code,

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const itemData = useItemDataQuery();
    
    return (
        <ChildComponent itemData={itemData.data}/>
    );
}


const ChildComponent =(itemData: any) => {
    const options = react.useMemo(() => { //error here
        const output = itemData && itemData[0].availableItems;
        return output;
    }
}, [itemData]);


return (
    <SelectMenu options ={options} value="hello"/>
);
```

}

itemData is an array of object like below

```
const itemData = [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        availableItems: [
            'Item1',
            'Item2',
        ],
    }
]
```

i am accessing availableItems with itemData && itemData[0].availableItems but still giving an error.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have tried like below

```
const options = react.useMemo(() => { 
        if (itemData && itemData.length > 0) {
            const output = itemData[0].availableItems;
            return output;
        }
    }
}, [itemData]);

this works. but under SelectMenuComponent the prop options shows error "no overload matches this call. Type Maybe<string>[]|undefined|null is not assignable to type .

return (
    <SelectMenu options ={options} value="hello"/> //error here
);
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: please provide your entire Error, its hard to understand what the problem is without it.

Comment: thanks. i have updated my question with what i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

`react` seems to be undefined.

Just add this statement at top of your imports:

```
import React from "react";
```

and use `React.useMemo`